# Ansible set become method

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am creating an inventory file and I want to become root as well but to do so I need to use this exact command on the nodes:

```
sudo rootsh -i -u root
```

Is there a way to do it?

And later on I would like to use that inventory for this command or something close to it:

```
ansible -i inventory_file -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_virtualization_role' -o -b all
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you find an answer to this, please [inform this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081472/ansible-become-with-rootsh)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I was unable to find a solution for my question no matter what and how I tried it.
(Also an other issue came up regarding this useage which could lock the users so I have given up on this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the solution just closing this.

I was unable to find a solution to put it in the inventory file and other problems have emerged regarding the useage.

Answer (score 0):

To run any 'sudo' commands on the nodes mentioned on your inventory file you will have to escalate privileges in your 'ansible.cfg' file by adding:

> 'become = True'

You can read more about Ansible Privilege Escalation Settings from [here.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#privilege-escalation-settings)

Alternately you can also mention it explicitly in your ansible playbook task, like this:

```
- name: execute this command
  command: "rootsh -i -u root"
  become: true
```